# At what point garbage collection is done in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, memory-management, garbage-collection, delete-operator

In [MDN Site about delete operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete), it's mentioned that

> Unlike what common belief suggests, the delete operator has nothing to
>   do with directly freeing memory. Memory management is done indirectly
>   via breaking references, see the memory management page for more
>   details.

So does this mean *Garbage Collector is not run when we 'delete' some object* or make it to 'null' and instead it runs periodically depending on some algorithm? Or does GC run continuously and wait for objects to be dereferenced?

Comment: Did you try to read the proposed page? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management

Comment: Javascript is a ***language***, so without specifyng what ***[engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_engine)*** you run it on, there is likely no answer that will be valid for all possible engines out there.

Comment: @smnbbrv, i think u didn't understand the question. I'am asking at what point of time GC looks for un- referenced objects and deallocates it.

Answer (score 0):

The delete operator delets only references and properties and not the object itself. There is no way to control when garbage collection happens in Javascript.Visit [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management#Garbage_collection) for more info.